# ImportError: libpng16.so.16

Tags: python, matplotlib, canopy

I'm getting the following error message when I try importing matplotlib.pylab in ipython on a node in a computer cluster. I am using Enthought Canopy 1.4.1.

Any idea how I could solve this?

```
/usr/lusers/marafi/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py in <module>()
     51 import matplotlib
     52 from matplotlib import afm
---> 53 from matplotlib import ft2font
     54 from matplotlib import rcParams, get_cachedir
     55 from matplotlib.cbook import is_string_like


ImportError: libpng16.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

Please update matplotlib in the Canopy Package Manager.

Comment: I just updated it to matplotlib-1.4.2. The same problem is occurring. /usr/lusers/marafi/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/font_manager.py in <module>()
     55 import matplotlib
     56 from matplotlib import afm
---> 57 from matplotlib import ft2font
     58 from matplotlib import rcParams, get_cachedir
     59 from matplotlib.cbook import is_string_like

Comment: What Linux distribution?

Comment: LSB Version:    :base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseServer
Description:    Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)
Release:        6.5
Codename:       Santiago